# Proving that $ 1-u = e^{-u - \,u^2/2 - \,u^3/3 -...}$

Tags: exponential-function

How can one see that for $-1 < u < 1$ we have the following equality $$ 1-u = e^{-u - \,u^2/2 - \,u^3/3 -...} \,\,\,\,?$$

It's probably easy to prove, however I've tried a couple of things so far (e.g. somehow using the series expansion of exp) but have failed.

Comment: The exponent for $e$ is the series expansion for $\log(1-u)$, then note the functions are inverses.

Comment: Try the series expansion of $\log$ instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this holds because for $-1\lt u \lt 1$, $-u-u^2/2-...=\ln(1-u)$ thus

$$e^{-u-u^2/2-...}=e^{\ln(1-u)}=1-u$$

Comment: Great thanks, I wasn't aware that the exponent was the series expansion of log(1-u).

Comment: no worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

For $|x|<1,$ using infinite Geometric Series,

$$(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$$

Integrate either sides to find $$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{x^r}r$$

Now  $$\ln y=z\implies y=e^z$$

If $z$ is finite real, real $y>0$

Answer (score 1):

Compute the Taylor expansion of the RHS:
$$\begin{align}
f(u)&=e^{-u-u^2/2-u^3/3-...},\\
f'(u)&=(-1-u-u^2-...)\ f(u)=\frac{f(u)}{u-1}\text{ (geometric series)},\\
f''(u)&=\frac{f'(u)(u-1)-f(u)}{(u-1)^2}=0\text{ (!)}
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$f(0)=1, f'(0)=-1, f''(0)=f'''(0)=...=0\implies f(u)=1-u.$$

Comment: Does not require knowledge of the development of $\ln$.